# Validation rule allowing update of Close Won Opps & change Owner

Tags: validation-rule, opportunity

Im fairly new to Validation rules. I am trying to create a validation rule for Opportunities which will only allow certain users, including Admin to change the status of a Closed Won Opp & to change the Owner of the record.

I have this so far, which works. But doesn't allow any other update to the record, including changing the owner

```
AND(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Closed Won"),
    NOT($Profile.Id = "2F00e4J000001FnQm")
)
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: `AND(
    ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Closed Won"),
    OR(
        $Profile.Name != "System Administrator",
        $User.Id != OwnerId,
        $User.Id != CreatedById
    ),
    NOT(
        OR(
            ISCHANGED(StageName),
            ISCHANGED(OwnerId)
        )
    )
)`  i have written this as per your question see if this works

Comment: Thank you Aman. Didn't work as still allows a user who is not Sys Admin to change the Stage from Closed Won & update the owner on the record?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the below rule:

```
AND(
ISPICKVAL(PRIORVALUE(StageName), "Closed Won"),
OR(
ISCHANGED(StageName),
ISCHANGED(OwnerId )
),
NOT($Profile.Id= "system admin id here"),    
NOT($Profile.Id= "other profile ids that need access")

)
```

This give access to system admin and other profile ids given in the rule to change ownership and stage name when stage is closed won. Also try to give the profile name if you are planning to use change set to deploy the rule.